# Creating wordpress user using form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a form page called Test Form with this form :

```
<div id="container">
<form action="wp-content/themes/max-magazine/TestForm.php" method="post" name="myForm">
User <input type="text"  name="uname" />
Email  <input id="email" type="text" name="uemail" />
Password  <input type="password"  name="upass" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
</div>
```

And in backend am having a php file named TestForm.php

```
<?php 
function create_account(){
$user = 'AccountID';
$pass = 'AccountPassword';
$email = 'email@domain.com';
if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
} 
}
add_action('init','create_account');
?>
```

Now if this function is defined in function.php then it works fine and create the user but same function in TestForm.php does not work.Please help

Also I will be fetching data from form like this :

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['upass'];
$email = $_POST['uemail'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the from action url correctly.
You just using this in your form

```
<form action="http://yourdomain.com/Test-form" method="post" name="myForm"/>
```

to give this action url to form follow the steps

**Step1** --Creating page

Here **Test-form** is a page you need to create in your wordpress dashboard through
**pages->Add new**, give name Test-form for page.
and on creating this page assign template as **Test form template** from Default template (see right panel of dashboard to select templates).

**step2** --creating page template  **Test form template**  in **TestForm.php**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test form template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php');//already have their works if your file location changed ?>
<!-- Your action page contents goes here -->
<?php
$user = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['upass'];
$email = $_POST['uemail'];
function create_account(){
$user = 'AccountID';
$pass = 'AccountPassword';
$email = 'email@domain.com';
if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
} 
}
do_action('init');
?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now save this in your theme directory as **TestForm.php**(wp-contents/themes/yourtheme/TestForm.php)
and this **TestForm.php** file will add **Test form template** , this you can add in **step1**

In your theme's functions.php file, or the like:

```
add_action('init','create_account');
```

In the page template **Test form template** use

```
do_action('init');
```

Comment: But the form is directing to the TestForm.php on click of submit button.So i dont find any issues with url

Comment: The problem am facing is the same function is working fine in functions.php but when i use it in TestForm.php then it doen't work.So is their a way that i can use function defined their in TestForm.php with arguments being the (user,pass,email)?

Comment: i think i just edit the answer as you expecting try the code,comment the issue if you have any more